# Is there any way at all to use a microphone with Canon SX720 HS?

Tags: canon

Note: This is a question camera, the ability of the camera in question, and help into deciding whether I need a new camera. This isn't a question about just "Video".

Is there any way at all to use a microphone with Canon SX720 HS? I sometimes make review videos or record videos of family/friend gatherings, and I would love to have the ability to use an external mic with this camera. Anything?

The question is also posted here: https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/62728324

Comment: I have removed that final sentence. It is on topic here, but always worth reading a particular site's scope before posting - click on the ? at the top right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - while this is a well featured point and shoot, it is not designed to accept external accessories other than those detailed on [page 146 in the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0300022616/01/pssx720hs-cu-en.pdf)

[image]